# Does a concave increasing function that goes through the origin always have a diminishing elasticity?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Consider a twice continuously differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}_+^0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$, $f'>0$, $f''<0$.

Does that function feature non-increasing elasticity, i.e. $$\frac{ \partial \frac{f'(x) x}{f(x)}}{\partial x} \leq 0\quad \forall x?$$

I am unable to prove this simple point, but also unable to find a counter example.

**EDIT:** I have made some progress, but it is not yet a proof. Take any $x>0$ and calculate the derivative on the LHS of the statement. The statement is true if (and only if)

$$ f'(x) x - f(x) \geq \frac{f''(x) f(x) x}{f'(x)}$$

Using a second order Taylor expansion we obtain

$$0=f(0)=f(x) - f'(x)x + 1/2 f''(x)x^2 - O(x^3).$$

Rearranging and plugging into the inequality we get

$$ f''(x)x^2/2 - O(x^3) \geq \frac{f''(x) f(x) x}{f'(x)}$$

Which (at least in a neighborhood of 0 or if $-O(x^3)\geq 0$) has a sufficient condition in

$$ f'(x) \leq 2\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$

Since $f(x)/x \geq f'(x)$ (because $f$ is concave, increasing and goes through the origin) that is true. Yet we don't know anything about what happens if $O(x^3) >0$ and we are far away from $x=0$.

Comment: $f$ and $x$ are both positive, so $$2\frac{f(x)}{x}< \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ is obviously false.

Comment: true. fair point. I changed that

Comment: @PaulSinclair But actually the conclusion holds. Because what we need is that 2 f(x)/x>f'(x). We know that f(x)/x>f'(x) so 2f(x)/x>f(x)/x tells us that 2f(x)/x>f'(x) holds

Comment: Except you are working backwards. You need to prove your inequality - that means you have to *start* with something you know and derive the inequality from it. Starting with the inequality and deriving from it something you know doesn't prove anything.

Comment: I do not follow. Where is the flaw? Here is what I do: (i) I take a statement. (ii) I derive an equivalent statement (at least under some conditions) and show that (iii) the equivalent statement is implied by the assumptions. Thus the original statement is implied by the assumptions.

So I prove something. The problem is: I don't prove anything if I can't assume the additional (sufficient) condition that we are either in the neighborhood of $0$ or that $O(x^3)$ has a particular sign.

Comment: Or to put different, going your way would to start with $f(x)/x>f'(x) \Rightarrow 2 f(x)/x > f'(x)$ and then work upwards my construction to show that this is equivalent to the statement to be proven. Since all are equivalents, that is the same thing, no? (notice the "if and only if")

Comment: The flaw is here: "I derive and equivalent statement". That "equivalent statement" is not always equivalent. To be equivalent, everything you do must be invertible. And if it is invertible, then it would be better to state it in that inverse direction, since it is the inverse direction you supposed to be proving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106849/discussion-between-johaschn-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: To clarify here: What I do is (imho):  statement to be shown "<=>" then (under additional condition) "<=" then "<=" and I end up with an assumption. That looks to me like a proof given the additional condition. But I am happy to be proven wrong (pun intended)

Comment: You've missed the point. If your object is to prove something, that means producing an argument that will convince *others* that it is true. Even if everything is reversible, why should your audience be expected to verify that reversibility themselves? You are supposed to convince them, and if you phrase it backwards, you've vastly weakened your argument. You've gotten away with it so far because your teachers have let it slide while getting other matters in your head. But at the level of math you are doing now, that changes. Learn to prove things in the correct order.

Comment: I take it that I haven't convinced you. I learned from that. I also take it, though, that you won't contribute to finding a counterexample or a proof to the problem (my proof is still half way only anyways no matter what my "teachers" think about it). Lastly on orders. My actual teachers have told me that what matters is the orders of arrows and not the order of presentation. I also have seen many proofs starting from the back because it makes it pedagogically more appealing. I  feel this is the case here. I would always do it again this way even at the risk of losing you specifically.

Comment: What I take is that you don't understand the difference between comments and answers. Comments are for making suggestions about improvements to your post. Answers are for actually addressing the question. I noted an error in your argument *as presented*. You corrected it, but felt I meant something more than that. I also noted that your work was presented backwards, and  you've gotten huffy about it, so I pointed *part* of why arguments should be presented in order (BTW your "arrows" as presented are backwards) This is your choice, and giving up on you is mine.

Comment: Great. So we all learned something even if not related to the problem.